Receiving 'No valid SOQL query' error using 'Extract' DataRaptor in Omnistudio
I'm new to omnistudio and I'm trying to extract data using extract DataRaptor. Please refer the below screenshots.




Just realised the 'Vlocity.NULL' in the first screen should be inside single quotations

Welcome to Omnistudio!
I would suggest you change your filter criteria to:

This will give you the results you are looking for (all Account records basically):

The debug log also kicked out the SOQL query that was run as:
SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Id != null LIMIT 50000

So by specifying Id <> '' it will translate to Id != null in the SOQL query
Good luck!
